# SQLDeveloper keeps resetting connection to database

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Oracle SQLDeveloper installed on a Mac. Versions are listed below:

> SQL Developer: Version 19.1.0.094, Build 094.2042
>
> Mac: macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G1012)
>
> Java: Java 8 Update 231

I have added multiple connections to various Oracle databases. One of the database is on a VirtualBox inside the mac itself and the others are hosted instances.

After connecting to a database and performing actions such as running SQL queries, running SQL scripts or compiling packages, the database connection gets reset when an execute command is issued.

For instance, let's say I ran two queries and when I execute a third query the connection resets. So far I have not identified any pattern. The reconnect happens when running SQL scripts or compiling packages as well.

I can confirm that it is not a database side setting as none of my colleagues face this issue. Additionally, I never faced this issue when connecting to the same databases from SQLDeveloper from my previous laptops.

Is there any setting or configuration that I can look at on SQLDeveloper side to address this?

Comment: What version of Oracle Database?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: the output of v$version (banner_full column) is "Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0". This is for the database that is hosted in a Linux Virtual Box machine on my Mac

Comment: your colleagues are connecting to a vbox on your mac? 19.1 has an 18c jdbc driver, you could try v19.2.1 which has a 19c jdbc driver

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: just to clarify regarding the connections that my colleagues are making: i am connecting to multiple databases using the SQLDeveloper and the issue seems to be present in all the databases. one of the database is hosted on the VM in my Mac and the version of that is given above. the other ones are hosted databases. these hosted ones are the ones to which my colleagues are connecting and running queries without facing reconnection issues. Thanks for the above recommendation, I'll try it out. For now, I have downloaded the latest SQLDeveloper. Testing that for a few days first.

Comment: I have the latest SQL Developer (19.4) + 18c DB on VM and I have this problem :(